# How to pass props to the screens when using Expo Router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-router

I need to pass `open` and `setOpen` to the index screen.

```
function RootLayoutNav() {
    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
            <Stack>
                <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{
                    headerShown: true,
                    headerLeft: () => (
                            <Pressable onPress={() => setOpen(true)}>
                                {({ pressed }) => (
                                   <Text>Open</Text>
                                )}
                            </Pressable>
                    ),
                }}/>
            </Stack>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Is there a way to pass them without creating complicated solutions such as context?

Answer (score 1):

Use `initialParams`:

```
<Stack.Screen    
      name="index" 
      options={{
            headerShown: true,
            headerLeft: () => (
                 <Pressable onPress={() => setOpen(true)}>
                       {({ pressed }) => (
                           <Text>Open</Text>
                       )}
                 </Pressable>
            )
      }}
      initialParams={{ open, setOpen }}    
/>
```

Then you can use it:

```
function IndexScreen({ route }) {
    const { open, setOpen } = route.params;


    return (
        // ...
    );
}

export default IndexScreen;
```